# series: can the result be zero for a continuous interval of its argument?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, divergent-series

I'm considering the series
$$ f_c(x) = \sum_{k=c}^\infty \left( c^{k-1} \binom{k}{c} \cdot \prod_{j=1}^{k-1} (x-1/j) \right) $$
where the parameter $c \in \mathbb N ,c \gt 0$ and fixed for a certain discussion.
Let's denote the product-term $ \prod_{j=1}^{k-1} (x-1/j)$ as $ y_k(x) $

First, I see, that for $x =1/m, m\in \mathbb N$ the series is finite *(the higher terms $y_{k \ge m}(1/m) = 0 $)* and gives an exact value. While this is obvious, it is not obvious to me, that, for all such *x* , *and even for all c (!)*, it seems that it is also true that $ f_{c \gt 0} (1/m) = 0 $ which I can approximate faily well using Pari/GP.

**Q1:** This looks somehow like a telescoping effect. Can it be shown, that for the so-constructed finite sums the result is always zero?

Next, if $ |x| \lt 1 \ne 1/m $ is a rational value with a non-simple fraction or is even irrational (the single terms do not vanish) then $ f_c(x) $ becomes a series with infinitely many terms. Still it seems, that for any such *x* the series converges for *c=1* and again it converges to zero. For example, using *400* terms, I got $f_1(0.8+\pi /1000,400) \lt 1e-38$ . Increasing the number of terms to *800* I got $f_1(0.8+\pi /1000,800) \lt 1e-76$ . Letting x approach *1* from below, I just needed more terms to always approximate zero (for negative *x* the terms have alternating signs, and their absolute values increase first before they begin to decrease).
For *c=2* it is similar, only that it must be  $ |x| \lt 1/2 $  and in general it seems $f_c(x) $ approaches zero whenever we have $ |x| \lt 1/c $

**Q2:** True? Is there an algebraic proof?

If $ x \lt -1/c $ the absolute value of the terms increase, but it seems, the series can always summed by Euler-summation, because the terms alternate in sign. Using that summation: again it seems, that the series always approaches zero.

**Q3:** From the properties of power series I know, that when a continuous interval of the argument leads to the same function-value, then the function must be the constant function. But this seems to be different here. Is there possibly a trivial answer for this?

*Remark: This is an extension of an earlier discussion of mine where I considered the construction of the formal series $f_c(x) $ based on a matrix-problem. That older question was not yet answered, so I thought, to develop it into a question on series (here with a Newton-basis) might help to get more insight.

Here are some references to older questions:

[The question as problem with an infinite matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89853)

[Learning the expression "Newton-basis"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120028)*