# Polynomial coefficients in exponential-series: how can I convert this into a composite of $\exp(x)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Assume we have the exponential-series $ \small \exp(x) = 1+ {x \over 1!}  + {x^2 \over 2! } + \cdots = \sum\limits_{k=0 }^\infty {x^k \over k!} $ modified with a polynomial in the coefficients
say $ \qquad \displaystyle f_1(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty { k^2 + k \over 2} {x^k \over k!} $
or $ \qquad \displaystyle  f_2(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty ( 15 k^3 + 15 k^2 - 10k - 8) {x^k \over k!} $
or in general
$ \qquad \displaystyle  f_3(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty ( d k^3 + c k^2 + b k + a) {x^k \over k!} $

-: is there a good formula/algorithm/scheme how this has to be expressed as composition of the $\exp(x)$-function? *(I know this can be solved using the derivatives and cancelling of k's in the polynomial with the factorials in the denominator - I'm asking for a handy/memorizable translation-formula )*

Because I can factor my examples under study: is there possibly a special handy scheme, if the polynomials are given in a form like this
$ \qquad \displaystyle  f_2(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty ( k-1)(k-2) {x^k \over k!} $     ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\frac{x^k}{k!}&=&\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{(k-1)!}=x\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}=xe^x;\cr
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2\frac{x^k}{k!}&=&x\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}=x\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)\frac{x^k}{k!}=x(x+1)e^x\cr
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^3\frac{x^k}{k!}&=&\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2\frac{x^k}{(k-1)!}=x\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)^2\frac{x^k}{k!}\cr
&=&x\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k^2+2k+1)\frac{x^k}{k!}=x[x(x+1)+2x+1]e^x\cr
&=&x(x^2+3x+1)e^x.
\end{eqnarray}
Hence
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (dk^3+ck^2+bk+a)\frac{x^k}{k!}&=&d\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^3\frac{x^k}{k!}+c\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2\frac{x^k}{k!}+b\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\frac{x^k}{k!}+a\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}\cr
&=&dx(x^2+3x+1)e^x+c(x^2+x)e^x+bxe^x+ae^x\cr
&=&[a+bx+c(x^2+x)+d(x^3+3x^2+x)]e^x\cr
&=&[a+(b+c+d)x+(c+3d)x^2+dx^3]e^x
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Very nice, thanks to all respondents. I'll accept this answer, because it starts a conversion-formula (...to be generalized...) for the coefficients for the polynomials $a+bk+ck^2+dk^3+...$ at the terms of the series into their equivalents at the exponential-function composition $A=a$,$B=(b+c+d)$ ... to become $(A+Bx+Cx^2+Dx^3+...)e^x)$ That's just what I'm after.

Answer (score 3):

[Dobiński's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DobinskisFormula.html) for the [Bell polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellPolynomial.html) is easily rearranged for your purposes:

$$\mathscr{B}_n(x)\exp\,x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k^n x^k}{k!}$$

A convenient representation for the Bell polynomials is

$$\mathscr{B}_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n\left\{n\atop k\right\}x^k$$

where $\left\{n\atop k\right\}$ is a Stirling subset number (Stirling number of the second kind).

Thus, in principle, one can always express a series of the form

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty p(k)\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

for a polynomial $p(k)$ in terms of a polynomial multiplied by $\exp\,x$.

Answer (score 2):

$$P_3=k(k-1)(k-2)=k^3-3k^2+2k$$
$$P_2=k(k-1)=k^2-k$$
$$P_1=k$$

And $\sum P_i \frac{x^k}{k!}=x^ie^x$

$$\begin{array}{ccl}
15k^3+15k^2-10k-8&=&15P_3+60k^2-40k-8\\
&=&15P_3+60P_2+20k-8\\
&=&15P_3+60P_2+20P_1-8P_0\\
\end{array}$$

Hence $$\sum(15k^3+15k^2-10k-8)\frac{x^k}{k!}=(15x^3+60x^2+20x-8)e^x$$

Comment: Note that this can be derived by differentiating the power series expansion for $e^x$.

Comment: @AlexBecker:True, that was part of my first attempt, but it was too complicated for paper&pen. I just missed a handy general translation recipe for the polynomial at the terms into that at the $e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with the given answers of @mercy and the other respondents I found now a very simple transformation scheme, which fits my needs perfectly.

If we denote the coefficients of the polynomial at the series-terms as row-vector $S = [a,b,c,d,...z] $, the coefficients at the x for the composition of the exponential-series with the vector $T=[A,B,C,D,...,Z] $ and the matrix of the Striling numbers  2'nd kind as **S2** where

$S2 = \small \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & . & . & . & . & . & . & \cdots \\
 0 & 1 & . & . & . & . & . &  \cdots  \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & . & . & . & . &  \cdots  \\
 0 & 1 & 3 & 1 & . & . & . &  \cdots  \\
 0 & 1 & 7 & 6 & 1 & . & . &  \cdots  \\
 0 & 1 & 15 & 25 & 10 & 1 & . &  \cdots  \\
 0 & 1 & 31 & 90 & 65 & 15 & 1 &  \cdots  \\
 \vdots   &\vdots    &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots
 \end{bmatrix}$ of appropriate size,

then by $ S \cdot S2 = T $ we get the required coefficients for the composition in **T**.

This helps also to solve the first step in my [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89853), because the polynomials in *x*, which describe the compositions of the exponential-series have all the factor $(x-1)$ in them. Then, if I set *x=1* it means, that all coefficients in the first column of the assumed "Null-matrix" are indeed zero.
My current [main question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178000) asks this in a different way; but if I change order of summation accordingly then I have by this, that the formal power series for the function $f_1(x)$ has just that zeros in all coefficients at *x*, so that indeed the function $f_1(x)$ must be zero for all $x$. Cute...